# installed keras and tensorflow but getting error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

i am getting the this importerror
even i have installed all the necessary modules like keras , tensorflow etc, 
i am not able to resolve it even working in conda environment.

> ImportError: No module named python.training

```
#Imports 
import os
from random import shuffle

#Keras imports
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
#Imports 
import os
from random import shuffle

#Keras imports
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
Using TensorFlow backend.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-383ae65daf54> in <module>()
      4 
      5 #Keras imports
----> 6 from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
      7 from keras.models import Sequential
      8 from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D

build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg/keras/__init__.py in <module>()

build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg/keras/utils/__init__.py in <module>()

build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg/keras/utils/conv_utils.py in <module>()

build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg/keras/backend/__init__.py in <module>()

build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in <module>()

ImportError: No module named python.training
```

Comment: could you print `sys.path` and show the directory structure of the `tensorflow` directory?

Comment: pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.4.1
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /Users/amitkumar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: wheel, six, protobuf, enum34, tensorflow-tensorboard, numpy

Comment: Your edit has completely changed the import error?

Comment: @roganjosh , i didn't get you, but i am adding that, previously i was showing the error with conda environment and this one is with system python2. even after changing the environment i am getting the same error

Comment: Your initial question showed an import error on `from tensorflow.python.training import moving_averages`. How can you not see that this is different since there is no explicit import of `tensorflow` in your new code?

Comment: @roganjosh, the codes are same only, previous one was with virtual environment.

Comment: @roganjosh  , how can i get this fixout?